# How do you create multiple configurations of an assembly quickly in Solidworks?

Tags: solidworks

One way is to go to the configurations manager, right click, and select add configuration.  This is super slow if you have many to add.  There must be a faster way, similar to how you create new configurations with a design table.

Answer (score -1):

Switch back from the configuration manager to the tab that shows all the parts that are in the assembly.  Right click any of them, select configure component.  The window that pops up will provide an excell-like interface with an option to add another configuration.  Click on it, give it a name, hit enter.  Immediately type the next name.  Keep going until they are all entered.  Voila.

[An even better answer!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yI6YEAt6kq8)